# Can I prevent mobile safari from auto-rotating the screen on ipod touch or iphone?

Tags: iphone, safari, ipod-touch

We have a web app that is being developed. It will be used on an ipod touch that is built into a tabletop. As it is basically horizontal, the ipod keeps changing its mind about which way up it is and keeps switching the orientation of the browser.

Is there a way to ask it to stop doing that? If not, is there an alternative browser that will let me prevent screen rotation that anyone can recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an API key, it would be pretty much trivial to make such an app. Just stick a `UIWebView` into a nib and hook up a text field for the address bar.

If you don't have access to dev tools, take a look at the built-in browsers in pretty much every app. Very few support rotation.

I imagine there is a 3rd party app that has some alternate functionality in addition to a web browser that might offer what you need. Beyond that is outside of the scope of stackoverflow….

Comment: I had not thought of trying this. I don't have an API key now, but think it is worth looking into.

Comment: @Andrew - your answer is inspiring (+1) but not definite. I have reopened this question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601282/can-i-prevent-mobile-safari-from-auto-rotating-the-screen-on-ipod-touch-or-iphone . If you had some more thoughts on the topic - please let us know.